# Where does the CHECKSUM metadata value for a table get stored in DBC Teradata catalog tables

Tags: teradata, checksum

Am looking to find out where does the Checksum metadata values of the datable got stored.
Here when I run a query

```
CREATE TABLE "mydb"."Table1", FALLBACK , SINGLE BEFORE JOURNAL , CHECKSUM = HIGH (
   "Column1" CHARACTER(5),
   "Column2" CHARACTER(5)
);
```

I can see the Journal options are store in the JournalFlag Column (http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/ index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1092_112A/ Appendix_A_System_Columns.019.05.html).

Which can be found using the query "select JournalFlag from DBC.Tables where DatabaseName = 'mydb' and TableName = 'Table1' "

Is there any such way to know the value of the Checksum for a given table from the Teradata catalog tables, or is there any store procedure of utility to find out the value of checksum for a given table ?

Thanks in advance !!

Regards,

Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

CHECKSUM can't be found in any system table, it's only in the table header (similar to BLOCKSIZE).

The only way to get this info using SQL is a SHOW TABLE, otherwise only a low-level command line utility should be able to extract this info. Probably FILER, but this is mainly for TD support...

Comment: Oh ok, so the only option is use the SHOW TABLE, parse the SQL to get the checksum value !!, a painful option, but it works :) thanks a lot.